# Android:How do I add Action bar to every list item in a List view?

Tags: android, listview, android-actionbar

I am trying to add an action bar to every list item in a list view that will display a number of options when clicked. I've tried googling but can't really find any solutions.Currently, my listview is part of a Relative Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/playback_error"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/error_horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/error_horizontal_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/error_vertical_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/error_vertical_padding"
            android:background="@color/error_message_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="Connectivity error!"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/playback_error">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I start?If I use a custom listview, how does the actionbar come into place?

Comment: Why don't you just add the ActionBar to the layout you use for the ListViews items?

Comment: Because I already have one overall action bar at the top right to give the general options. However, I still need one action bar for each list item that displays options specific to that list item. (Such as deleting that item or queuing that item for some task.)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I meant why don't you add a `ToolBar` to your items?

Comment: If you only need the actions from the toolbar consider an ActionMenuView. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ActionMenuView.html

Answer (score 0):

I have figured that using a PopUpMenu would be more suitable for my situation.